# Scala action is not executing to store json object on ajax Submit into Postgresql database using Play Framework and Scala?

Tags: jquery, json, postgresql, scala, playframework

I have one json object in my view page(index.coffee), that I am sending to Scala controller class to store in Postgresql database through jQuery/ajax, after clicking my Submit button. I have done the following:(controller, model and database table), but I am not seeing any json data in database table after clicking of Submit button, even I cannot see any error  and my println() message on console(I hope addJson() action is not executing).I am not sure what and where I am doing wrong in my entire code from all the files ? As my Play Framework server(2.2.3) is connected to my database(I can see the message on console saying that: [info] play - database [default] connected at: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb).Please let me know where I am doing wrong and thanks in advance.

app.scala:

```
package controllers
import play.api.mvc._
import play.libs.Json;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc.Request
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.mvc.AnyContent;
import play.libs.Json;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import anorm._
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms.{single, nonEmptyText}
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}
import anorm.NotAssigned
import models.Jsoncontent
import play.api.Play.current
import views._
import models._

class Application extends Controller {

 //def saveJsonData = Action { request =>
  //val body: AnyContent = request.body
  //val jsonBody: Option[JsValue] = body.asJson
  //jsonBody.map {json =>
  //jsonBody.map {dao =>
   //dao.persist(json) 
   //Ok("Saved") 
 // }}.getOrElse {
   // BadRequest("Expecting text/json request.body") 
 // }
  //}


val jsonForm = Form(
    single("content" -> nonEmptyText)
  )

  def addJson() = Action { implicit request =>
  println("Inside addJson() ... !")
    jsonForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => BadRequest,
      {
        case (content) =>
          Jsoncontent.create(Jsoncontent(NotAssigned, content))
          Redirect(routes.Application.index())
      }
    )
  }

}
```

Jsoncontent.scala:

```
package models

import anorm._
import anorm.SqlParser._
import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.libs.json.{Json,JsValue}
import anorm.features.parameterWithUntypedName

case class Jsoncontent (
  id: Pk[Long], content: String
)

object Jsoncontent {
  val extractor = {
    get[Pk[Long]]("id") ~
    get[String]("content") map {
      case id~content => Jsoncontent(id, content)
 }
 }

  def create(jsondata: Jsoncontent): Unit = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("INSERT INTO jsondata(content) VALUES({content})").on(
        'content -> jsondata.content
      ).executeInsert()
    }
  }
}
```

index.coffee:

```
do ->
  jsonContent = {}
  $('input[id=buttonId]').click ->
    name = $(this).attr('name')
    jsonContent[name] = $(this).val()
    return
  $('#submit').click ->
    $('input[id=fileId]').each ($i) ->
      name = $(this).attr('name')
      jsonContent[name] = $(this).val()
      $.ajax
      type: 'POST'
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      dataType: 'json'
      url: '/addJson'
      data: JSON.stringify(jsonContent)
      success: (data) ->
        alert 'data saent' +data
        console.log data
        return
      error: (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        alert 'error found'
        return
      return
    console.log JSON.stringify(jsonContent)
    return
  return
```

routes:

```
POST    /addJson                    @controllers.Application.addJson
```

table:

```
CREATE TABLE jsondata (
  id                        serial PRIMARY KEY,
  content                   json NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Check the console for the error detail, if any. Note that you are using unsafe/deprecated Anorm code `anorm.features.parameterWithUntypedName`

Comment: @cchantep, thanks for reply, as I am not getting any errors on my console, few warnings I am getting even if I delete/keep the above statement, but my application is executing fine. But if I click on my Submit button only, it is giving like: Bad Request:http://localhost:9000/addJson.

Comment: So you need to add some debug to gather more info to be able to understand

Comment: of course, but I am not sure that how can I send my json object to scala controller class that is my issue

Comment: You can have a look at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonHttp

Comment: @cchantep, can we have chat discussion please ?

Comment: @cchantep, this time I am not getting any error on console after clicking Submit button(like: any bad request), but it is not storing in database table, I am not sure where I am doing wrong ? Please let me know what I am missing and wrong ? Thanks in advance. I have modified question, ajax code and description now.

Comment: @cchantep, after several trials, I am getting the error like: value insert is not a member of play.api.libs.json.JsValue in my scala controller class, don't know why I am getting this error ? Could you please check once let me know at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989311/value-insert-is-not-a-member-of-play-api-libs-json-jsvalue-in-play-framework-and. Thanks in advance.