# How to use json object from Javascript in Scala to connect with database?

Tags: jquery, json, scala, playframework, coffeescript

I am new to Scala and Play, learning now a days, I have a json object, that I need to send to my scala controller class and connect with the database to store. I don't know how to do this ? Please help me regarding this.

```
(function() {
  var jvalue;
  jvalue = {};
  $('input[id=buttonId]').click(function() {
    var name;
    name = $(this).attr('name');
    jvalue[name] = $(this).val();
  });
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    $('input[id=fileId]').each(function($i) {
      var name;
      name = $(this).attr('name');
      jvalue[name] = $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jvalue));//I need to use jvalue object in scala class to store and connect with my database(how can I use or parse or route to scala to use)
  });
})();
```

scala:

```
def addJson = Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { implicit request =>
    jsonForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => BadRequest,
      {
        case (content) =>
          Jsoncontent.insert(Jsoncontent(NotAssigned, content))
          Redirect(routes.Application.index())
      }
   )
 }
```

routes

```
POST    /addJson                    @controllers.Application.addJson
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use an HTML form or ajax to send data from the browser to the server.

If you're using jquery:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/addJson",
  data: jvalue
});
```

But if you're using ajax (as opposed to a form), you should not redirect after the action. You should do:

```
case (content) =>
  Jsoncontent.insert(Jsoncontent(NotAssigned, content))
  NoContent
```

Or return something like:

```
Ok(Json.obj({"success": true}))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, If I send data to server and then how to use that data in scala to connect and store in database ?

Comment: @Alvaro Carrasco, it's giving error like Bad Request: Not found http://localhost:9000/addJson ?

Comment: @Dhana, which is it? BadRequest and NotFound are 2 different errors. Can you post a transcript of the request (including request headers)? You can get it from the chrome developer tools (network tab).

Comment: @Nag have you tried this? https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDatabase

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco, I am not getting any error now on browser and console, but it's not storing my json object in postgresql database after clicking Submit button and I am not sure where and what I am doing wrong ?(I am using jQuery/ajax+Anorm+Play+Postgresql) Can you please check it once at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921089/not-stroing-json-object-on-ajax-submit-into-postgresql-database-using-play-frame

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco, as it is not giving any errors and any println() message on my console, Can you please check and let me know where and what I am doing wrong ? as I am facing these type of issues for this task from last few days as I am new to these entire things !! Please help me and thanks in advance ! (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921089/scala-action-is-not-executing-to-store-json-object-on-ajax-submit-into-postgresq)

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco, I can see some println message on my console after several trials, but it's giving error like: value insert is not a member of play.api.libs.json.JsValue in scala controller class, don't know why I'm getting this error ? I have created the same query at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989311/value-insert-is-not-a-member-of-play-api-libs-json-jsvalue-in-play-framework-and, Could you please help me at this !!